# django-filter searching on multiple fields and models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm looking for a way to filter two inputs(***name*** and ***place***) from two models (Photographer and Location); but, MultipleChoiceFilter seems like it doesn't work for me because I need to add more **complex logic** which performs in my custom filter as below.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class SearchResultFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter('Photographer')
    place = filters.CharFilter(method='location_filter', distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Photographer
        fields = ('name')

   def location_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
       """My complex logic"""
         .
         .
         .
       model = models.Location.filter(Q(location__icontains=value))
       return model
```

The question is " Is there a way I can put ***name*** input field in my location_filter, so that I can filter two inputs (***name*** and ***place***) in this function and return a wanted querySet from here".

I tried to use self.name in location_filter; however, an error log produced. I guess "name" here is not an class variable

Answer (score 0):

You could mimic the behavior of Django builtin multiple search using `?q=<value>`

```
from django.db.models import Q

def multiple_search(queryset, name, value):
    queryset = queryset.filter(Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(place__icontains=value))
    return queryset

class SearchResultFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(label='name or place', method=multiple_search)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. But doing this way, it means there is only one input from GET request. I'm expecting to retrieve two fields for GET request like searching for "John" and "England". The system will query "John" from Photographer model and query "England" from Location model, which has Photographer model as a foreign key here. Please guide me If I didn't get it correctly.